# Easiest way to upgrade php to latest version?

Tags: upgrade, php

I'm seeing info on how to upgrade from a specific version to another, and that is what I want to do (currently 3.3.6), but is there a simple command to do this?  I'm a complete ubuntu/linux noob so I have no idea what I'm talking about, I just want to upgrade php because my current version maybe limiting the amount of input elements that I can post to the following page.

Comment: I see the current Ubuntu version as 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6.  The latest for download from php.net is 5.3.10 - is that what you'd like to upgrade to?

Comment: yes, sorry I should have specified.

Comment: I think you are probably going to be better off debugging your PHP problems then upgrading. The exception would be that if you identified a bug that is known to be resolved by upgrading. In that case, personally I would compile php. Compiling php is (rather) trivial if you know php well, and know what you want, but if you are new to compiling and new to php, it can be difficult. Perhaps ask about your php problem first.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I've been told that the latest version does fix this issue. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505192/php-post-limited-to-1000-variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as if the problem is still under discussion on your question in stackoverflow, so ...

IMO you have two options:

### dot.deb

dot.deb has php packages and I have used them on Ubuntu before.

Add the dot.deb repository

```
sudo echo "deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Install php5

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-common php5-suhosin
```

### compile php

From the precise repository - This may be safer ;)

```
apt-get install ubuntu-dev-tools
pull-lp-source php5 precise
dpkg-source -x php5_5.3.10-*.dsc
apt-get build-dep php5
cd php5-5.3.10
debuild binary
```

This second method was pulled from [How to update to PHP 5.3.10 in 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102117/how-to-update-to-php-5-3-10-in-10-04)

Comment: thanks, i resolved the issue from the other question but I'm going to upgrade anyways.